# How to bind apache with python3.4?

Tags: python, django, apache

I trying to `bind apache server with`python 3.4`. So, I have edited`httpd.conf` like below.

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/eachone/Project/MW_Service/MW_Service/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess MW_Service python-path=/home/eachone/Project/MW_Service:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup MW_Service

<Directory /home/eachone/Project/MW_Service/MW_Service>
<Files wsgi.py>
    Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /home/eachone/Project/MW_Service/static/
<Directory /home/eachone/Project/MW_Service/static>
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then I restart my `apache web server`. and I access to the web service.
I got this message :

> Service Temporarily Unavailable
>   The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.'

So, I refer to `/var/log/httpd/error_log`. see below

```
[Thu Aug 13 14:18:06 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_wsgi/4.4.13 Python/2.6.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 13 14:18:11 2015] [error] [client 2xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=2977): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'MW_Service' on '/etc/httpd/logs/wsgi.2974.0.1.sock' as user with uid=48.
[Thu Aug 13 14:18:13 2015] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=2978): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'MW_Service' on '/etc/httpd/logs/wsgi.2974.0.1.sock' as user with uid=48.
```

In the error_log,  Python 2.6.6 is loaded. But I want to use `3.4`. How can I solve this?

Comment: maintainance downtime or capacity problem ? have u looked at your server capacity ?

Comment: I find a solution. when you configure the source code, point to python3.4 like this ./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3.4